# fastest hacks for deploying a Sinatra app under nginx and thin (linux ofcourse)

Tags: ruby, linux, nginx, sinatra, thin

I am trying to figure out best practices of deploying a sinatra app under nginx and thin! any guidelines or sourcecode will be appreciated.

I don't want to use passenger nor Apache.. as my hunch is nginx and thin will be a faster combination. on the other hand, can thin be faster on its own without nginx?? this will be my next thing to find out.

Thank you all for your interest.

Comment: Take a look at http://railscasts.com, most of the deployment screencasts can easily be used with sinatra instead of rails.

Answer (score 1):

I sugest you benchmark your Sinatra app with unicorn, puma and thin before deciding on either one. For my app, I found that the performance was much better for unicorn than thin, but only at high loads.

You can read my results at:

http://ylan.segal-family.com/blog/2012/08/20/better-performance-on-heroku-thins-vs-unicorn-vs-puma/

Make sure that your benchmarks are in an environment as close as possible to your expected production environment (I used a staging server).